# one and twice differentiability of integral operator and contraction

Tags: derivatives, contraction-mapping

I am not quite sure about how to prove differentiability of a function.
I know by definition, if a function is differentialbe at a point, then the limit

> $$\lim_{x\to a} \dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$
> exists.

So do we prove that limit exists by proving the left side limit equals right side limit?

Is this the only way to prove differentiability?

Then for such an integral equation

> $$u(x)=x\int_o^x t^2 \cos(u(t))dt , x\in [-1,1],$$

we can first use chain rule to prove that $u'(x)=\int_o^x t^2 \cos(u(t))dt + x \cdot x^2\cos(u(x)) $ so that $u'(x)$ exists.

Then to prove that $u'$ is differentiable, can we again use the chain rule to prove that $u''(x)=x^2\cos(u(x))+3x^2\cos(u(x))-x^3\sin(u(x))\cdot u'(x) $ exists because $u'(x)$ has been proven to exist?

The last problem is how to prove that $u(x)$ is a contraction mapping? I currently always fail to get a parameter $c\in [0,1)$ When I calculate $|u(x)-u(y)|\le c|x-y|$. What I get is $\frac{4}{3}$ or $1$.

Answer (score 1):

The definition is technically the "only way" to prove differntiability, but there are some results (that follows from this definition) that may be useful for you.

For instance

1. A product of differntiable functions is differentiable.
2. All polynomials are differentiable, this includes $f(x)=x$.
3. For a measurable function $f$, the function $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt$ is differentiable whenever $f$ is continuous.

I'll leave the rest for you.